# What different types of context could be used in place of an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob

I was reading through admob mediation documentation and I seen this but im quite confused, because I thought when you use "this" it is referring to the activity you are in.  It says they recommend passing in an Activity instance e.g below.  I thought this was the only possible way does anyone know an example of what would be a context I would pass in thats not my current activity ?

```
adView = new AdView(this);
```

[image]

Comment: You could pass any `Context`, for example a `Service` or the global application `Context` you get by calling `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: if I use "this" in onCreate() does it refer to the current activity ?

Comment: If you are in `onCreate()` of an `Activity`, then `this` refers to that `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I was reading through admob mediation documentation and I seen this but im quite confused, because I thought when you use "this" it is referring to the activity you are in."

You're slightly incorrect. `this` is referring to your current object. From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

For example, `this` in anonymous class will refer to the object class:

```
View view;
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
          // this will refer to View.OnClickListener object.
        }
      });
```

---

> I thought this was the only possible way does anyone know an example
>   of what would be a context I would pass in thats not my current
>   activity ?

You can also create the AdView inside the `Application` class, though that something I never recommended:

```
public MyApp extends Application {
  private AdView mAdView;

   ...
   public void createAdView() {
     // this will refer to MyApp which is a context.
     mAdView = new AdView(this);

     ...
     // the rest is history
   }
}
```

Or someone will create an Util to generate the `AdView` but forget to restrict the Context to Activity only:

```
public AdUtil {
  private AdUtil(){}

  ...

  // Here the parameter context can be Application, Activity, etc.
  public static AdView createAdView(Context context) {
    AdView adView = new AdView(context);

    ...
    return adView;
  }
}
```

Comment: So if “this” is inside the onCreate method then it is referring to the activity, but if my AdView has a listener that I implement inside onCreate() and then use “this” inside of that ad listener it no longer refers to the activity but to the AdView listener ? When you gave the example of the listener is “anonymous” class a type of class or you were just using it as a name example.  Also is there a way to like hover over the “this” text and see what it’s referring to in each case that it is used ?

Comment: In the last example you gave with AdUtil, what is the "this" inside ad view referring to ?

Comment: @Julian: I'm really sorry for the late response, the `this` in AdView()` should be a context. I'll update the answer.